# CSP with a Service Worker

Tags: service-worker, content-security-policy

I want to implement CSP on my site, but also have a Service Worker that caches resources and provides a notice if you are offline. I have defined the following policy:

```
style-src 'self'; object-src 'none'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; worker-src 'self'; frame-ancestors 'none';
```

Google's CSP evaluator gives a warning about the init function for the worker - because inline scripts can be used to do bad things - even though I have specified to only load workers from my domain (worker-src 'self').

What is the preferred way to whitelist this function?

```
<script>
   if (navigator.serviceWorker) {
     navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js')
     .then( function (registration) {
       console.log('Success!', registration.scope);
     })
     .catch( function (error) {
       console.error('Failure!', error);
}); }
</script>
```

Comment: What does "init function for the worker" refer to? What's the actual code that's being run, as is it inline in a `<script>` tag within your HTML?

Comment: It's really just a basic service worker - code is above. Although I've deployed them on a few sites, this is the first time I've tried to implement CSP as well, so I don't know if this can be abstracted to its own script. E.g, Could you have `setup.js` initialize `sw.js`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Even if you have restricted the ability to load workers, inline script tags can be used to execute [XSS attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)).

CSP [prevents XSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP#Mitigating_cross_site_scripting) by blocking all inline scripts. With a `'unsafe-inline'` directive, the effectiveness of CSP is greatly reduced, hence it is better to use other methods.

### Method 1: separate file

You can put the scripts into another file, like loadWorker.js, and include it via a regular script tag:

loadWorker.js:

```js
if (navigator.serviceWorker) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js')
    .then(function (registration) {
      console.log('Success!', registration.scope);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.error('Failure!', error);
    });
}
```

Your html file:

```html
<script src="./loadWorker.js"></script>
```

### Method 2: Using a hash

CSP allows inline script if you explicitly allow specific scripts [using a hash](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp/#if_you_absolutely_must_use_it).

The hash for the following js

```js
   if (navigator.serviceWorker) {
     navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js')
     .then( function (registration) {
       console.log('Success!', registration.scope);
     })
     .catch( function (error) {
       console.error('Failure!', error);
}); }
```

is `'sha256-vTdjucjBZWvbihWowJ2vrpjYlv4kalHHBIgd7vBr124='`.

Add it to your CSP header like so: `Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'sha256-vTdjucjBZWvbihWowJ2vrpjYlv4kalHHBIgd7vBr124='`.

Note: any changes to the code, including whitespace will change the hash. You will need to [recalculate the hash](https://report-uri.com/home/hash) and replace your header.
This method is cumbersome and not recommended

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense. Good to have you here.